# Jackson serialization of OffsetDateTime with DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME ignores zero milliseconds

Tags: java, spring, serialization, jackson, offsetdatetime

I have a class that will get serialized into JSON with the following attribute:

```
  @JsonProperty("validTo")
  @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat(iso = org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
  private OffsetDateTime validTo;
```

I'm also using the default spring-boot ObjectMapper with Jackson. This works fine if the `validTo` DateTime has non-zero mili/nanoseconds. However, if they are zero, the result will not include them at all.

Value `OffsetDateTime.of(2000, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 1000000, ZoneOffset.UTC)` would correctly translate to `2000-10-10T10:10:10.001Z`

But `OffsetDateTime.of(2000, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 0, ZoneOffset.UTC)` would incorrectly translate to `2000-10-10T10:10:10Z`

Why is that?
The javadoc of the format used in the annotation describes it as `The most common ISO Date Time Format yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX — for example, "2000-10-31T01:30:00.000-05:00".`, which appears to include the zeros.

Comment: The documentation of [OffsetDateTime#toString--](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#toString--) mentions it clearly: **The format used will be the shortest that outputs the full value of the time where the omitted parts are implied to be zero.**

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash That is a good point, but in my case, I was changing it to a string via the formatter, not the `toString()` itself. The formatter does not specify this, and I doubt the formatter utilizes the `toString()`.
I guess this is simply the way it works to remove unnecessary data, but it can be a pain if the parser requires a specific format :/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Jackson ignores `@DateTimeFormat` annotation and the real serialization happens in `com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.ser.OffsetDateTimeSerializer`.

You can test it if you annotate the field like this (it won't affect the result):

```
@JsonProperty("creationDateTime")
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy")
private OffsetDateTime validTo;
```